# Create new data from the overlap of two polygons/polylines

Tags: python, math, vector, numerical-methods

If we have two vector data such as polygons or polylines (shown in graph below). How can we get find the overlap and create a new x,y vector data for this new shape? (or simply get the area of the new shape.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = [10, 20, 40, 50, 50, 40, 20, 10, 10];
y1 = [20, 10, 10, 20, 40, 50, 50, 40, 20];

x2 = [30, 60, 30, 0, 30];
y2 = [40, 50, 70, 60, 40];

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x1, y1)
ax.plot(x2, y2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

For example, for the above graph where the intersections are, can we get the x,y coordinates/data for this new shape created from the overlap? or get the area of it instead?

Comment: We can. Compute line intersections and "paste" the lines together.

Comment: hmm thank you, ill give this a go

Comment: @YvesDaoust because it is?

Comment: @AnderBiguri: I mean, how does this help the OP ? Anyone can see it.

Comment: @YvesDaoust anyone can go and google how to do those steps too! Yet here we are. I explained the steps, so OP can go and research how to do those individually by themselves. Because that is what I (and others in SO) expect from OPs.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: you explained nothing, just threw a few words, which a not even relevant keywords.

Comment: @Yves the ones you used in your almost link only answer.... Yeah.

Answer (score 2):

Constructing the intersection of two polygons is uneasy in the general case. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatti_clipping_algorithm

When the polygons are convex, as in your example, you can use the Sutherland-Hodgman algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutherland%E2%80%93Hodgman_algorithm

Comment: that seems interesting, i never seen this method before. i'll try put it in code update later